# Custom spacing between recyclerview items

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, linearlayoutmanager

I need to display items similar to a hamburger.
Each element has a different height, but the distance between them should be always the same. I tried to use LinearLayoutManager, but spaces between items were too big. I created custom LinearLayoutManager but it doesn't work as I expected. How I should make spacing like 16dp or 50 px between ImageView.
I also need to make no spacing for the same type of items, but this problem is less important.

```
class CustomLinearLayoutManager(context: Context) : LinearLayoutManager(context) {

    private val horizontalSpace: Int
        get() = width - paddingEnd - paddingStart

    private val verticalSpace: Int
        get() = height - paddingBottom - paddingTop

    override fun generateDefaultLayoutParams(): RecyclerView.LayoutParams {
        return spanLayoutSize(super.generateDefaultLayoutParams())
    }

    override fun generateLayoutParams(c: Context, attrs: AttributeSet): RecyclerView.LayoutParams {
        return spanLayoutSize(super.generateLayoutParams(c, attrs))
    }

    override fun generateLayoutParams(lp: ViewGroup.LayoutParams): RecyclerView.LayoutParams {
        return spanLayoutSize(super.generateLayoutParams(lp))
    }

    private fun spanLayoutSize(layoutParams: RecyclerView.LayoutParams): RecyclerView.LayoutParams {

        if (orientation == HORIZONTAL) {
            layoutParams.width = (horizontalSpace / itemCount)
        } else if (orientation == VERTICAL) {
            layoutParams.height = (verticalSpace / itemCount)

        }
        return layoutParams
    }

    override fun canScrollVertically(): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun canScrollHorizontally(): Boolean {
        return false
    }

}
```

RecyclerView_item.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/RecyclerFood_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ingredientPic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/display_image_of_ingredient"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Fragment_layout.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/DishFragmentLayout"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="my.custom.food-app.MainActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/DishList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```